# jQuery number plugins in Bootstrap is no working

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQquery plugins bootstrap number-input.I gave jQuery link and CSS link like

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>template/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>  
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/js/bootstrap-formhelpers-number.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"> </script>  
</head>
```

and then my code is

```
<?php
  $data = array('id' => 'target');
  echo form_open(base_url().'/index.php/account/authentication',$data);
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control bfh-number" data-min="5" data-max="25">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

But it is not working.I checked path again and again.what am I doing wrong.I am using codeigniter and bootstrap.

Comment: You'll need to provide a working example e.g. an URL or on jsfiddle. Your server-side code doesn't really help here.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the HTML output of the form_open() function. If the `<FORM>` tag is malformed the text input inside it won't turn to bfh-number.